# How can I vectorize this python count sort so it is absolutely as fast as it can be?

Tags: python, performance, sorting

I am trying to write a count sort in python to beat the built-in timsort in certain situations. Right now it beats the built in sorted function, but only for very large arrays (1 million integers in length and longer, I haven't tried over 10 million) and only for a range no larger than 10,000. Additionally, the victory is narrow, with count sort only winning by a significant margin in random lists specifically tailored to it.

I have read about astounding performance gains that can be gained from vectorizing python code, but I don't particularly understand how to do it or how it could be used here. I would like to know how I can vectorize this code to speed it up, and any other performance suggestions are welcome.

Current fastest version for just python and stdlibs:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

def untimed_countsort(unsorted_list):
    counts = {}
    for num in unsorted_list:
        try:
            counts[num] += 1
        except KeyError:
            counts[num] = 1

    sorted_list = list(
        chain.from_iterable(
            repeat(num, counts[num])
            for num in xrange(min(counts), max(counts) + 1)))
    return sorted_list
```

- All that counts is raw speed here, so sacrificing even more space for speed gains is completely fair game.
- I realize the code is fairly short and clear already, so I don't know how much room there is for improvement in speed.
- If anyone has a change to the code to make it shorter, as long as it doesn't make it slower, that would be awesome as well.
- Execution time is down almost 80%! Now three times as fast as Timsort on my current tests!

The absolute fastest way to do this by a LONG shot is using this one-liner with numpy:

```
def np_sort(unsorted_np_array):
    return numpy.repeat(numpy.arange(1+unsorted_np_array.max()), numpy.bincount(unsorted_np_array))
```

This runs about 10-15 times faster than the pure python version, and about 40 times faster than Timsort. It takes a numpy array in and outputs a numpy array.

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a better site for this question.

Comment: Use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and never loop over a numpy ndarray unless you've searched the documentation, consulted with other programmers, and determined that what you're trying to do cannot be done with vectorized builtins.

Comment: From my brief exploration of numpy, their documentation seems to be extremely lacking. Do you have any tips about how, specifically, I could implement numpy-driven performance boosts on this sort?

Comment: Getting rid of the branch statements by using try catch blocks might provide a small speed boost.

Comment: Changed to try/except block, actually lead to a pretty big performance boost. Now I get around 0.43 seconds instead of 0.48 seconds on a million-integer input. Updating main post.

Comment: Instead of try/except, just use a `defaultdict(int)` and unconditionally do `counts[num] += 1`.

Comment: (Also, note that `except Exception, e` is a bad way to catch that exception. `except KeyError` would be better, as it specifies the type of error you're looking for and lets other exceptions propagate, and it doesn't save a reference to an exception object we don't care about.)

Comment: Changed exception block and used chain and repeat from itertools to speed up building the final sorted list. Now runs on average .2 seconds for 1 million random integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With numpy, this function reduces to the following:

```
def countsort(unsorted):
    unsorted = numpy.asarray(unsorted)
    return numpy.repeat(numpy.arange(1+unsorted.max()), numpy.bincount(unsorted))
```

This ran about 40 times faster when I tried it on 100000 random ints from the interval [0, 10000). [`bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) does the counting, and [`repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) converts from counts to a sorted array.

Comment: This is the key:  Anything you can get the interpreter to do in native code (rather than in python instructions) is going to be vastly faster.

Comment: I am totally blown away. This is awesome, runs twice as fast as my current fastest work, more than four times as fast as the built in sort - 1.5 seconds on 10 million integers. Well done sir. Is there any way to get it to return an ordinary list?

Comment: You could call the output's [`tolist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method, but depending on how much math you're doing, it might be better to keep the array. (My timing data used a numpy array as input for the numpy version and a list as input for the no-numpy version.)

Comment: Just ran this on 100,000,000 integers, 42 seconds as opposed to timsort's 110. On 1 million integers it ran in 0.014 s as opposed to timsort's 0.58. 41 times faster, that is some really really serious performance.

Answer (score 1):

Without thinking about your algorithm, this will help get rid of most of your pure python loops (which are quite slow) and turning them into comprehensions or generators (always faster than regular `for` blocks).  Also, if you have to make a list consisting of all the same elements, the `[x]*n` syntax is probably the fastest way to go.  The `sum` is used to flatten the list of lists.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def countsort(unsorted_list):
    lmin, lmax = min(unsorted_list), max(unsorted_list) + 1
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for j in unsorted_list:
        counts[j] += 1
    return sum([[num]*counts[num] for num in xrange(lmin, lmax) if num in counts])
```

Note that this is not vectorized, nor does it use numpy.

Comment: Hmm. sorted_list += [num]*counts[num] is significantly (more than twice as) fast as the way I was doing it, but strangely using the Counter class slows down execution immensely. Mixing and matching with a try/catch block and your method for extending the sorted_list we can bring down time to under .35 seconds on average! (Timsort gets about .55!)

Comment: @sortfiend Does using a defaultdict work faster than Counter or the `try/except` block?

Comment: I have not tried defaultdict, but my feeling is that would require allocating the entire range twice, which seems significantly slower. I will test it out and come back.

Comment: OK.  Either way, my solution will never beat the numpy solution.  I just wanted to offer a pure python version in case you didn't have access to numpy.

Comment: defaultdict is just a tiny bit slower than try/except. The list comprehension for the return value is just a tiny bit faster, so I will be changing to that. However, I'm having a tiny bit a problem. When I drop the list comprehension format (with lmin and lmax changed so that they are defined in the comprehension) the list is sorted, but each number is in its own list. Like: [[1, 1], [2, 2, 2]] etc. How do I fix that?

I'm still curious to work on a python solution because it is interesting. But yes, that numpy solution is crazy.

Comment: On double-triple checking, defaultdict is actually faster. That makes your solution the fastest setup yet! EDIT: Scratch that again. Defaultdict is faster for smaller arrays (under a million) but the old version is faster for larger arrays.

Comment: I should have realized you would get the list of lists... I think you will have to go back to the `+=` syntax.  OR, you could put a `sum` around the list comprehension (which will flatten a list of lists), but this will just be some extra overhead.

Comment: I tried to fix it by doing another comprehension on the new list, but that slows it down too much. It's a shame, because it is faster than another try/except block by about 10%.

Comment: Oh man.  If you have 1 million elements, forget about this solution and just go with numpy.

Comment: A million elements runs in .3 seconds, but I'm not doing this because I actually need to sort a million elements, I'm just doing it because I'm doing it. I'm pretty satisfied with a 40% gain over Timsort without numpy though, so I'll put it to rest.